# How we can upload a file programmatically in sugarcrm into the upload folder

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar Pro 6.4 and inside a customized view I want to upload a file in the upload folder in sugarcrm. For this I am using standard input type="file".

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

The user can select the file successfully, but how can I upload the selected file programmatically into the Upload folder in sugarcrm directory structure?

Comment: i have submitted the form and use an action defined in the controller.php file to get that file in that action method in the controller file i get the  filename but how can i upload the user selected file to the upload folder and use its name to open it in future.

Comment: Maybe you can show what you did in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after changing the fieldnames where necessary

```
<?php

require_once('include/upload_file.php');

$upload_file = new UploadFile('uploadfile');
$do_final_move = 0;
if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']) && $upload_file->confirm_upload())
{
  $this->bean->filename = $upload_file->get_stored_file_name();
  $this->bean->file_mime_type = $upload_file->mime_type;

  $do_final_move = 1;
}
$this->bean->save();
if ($do_final_move)
{
  $upload_file->final_move($this->bean->id);
}

?>
```